# how to run docker to the same network with another docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, robotframework

I have a website docker container `(Docker-A)` running on network `sts_sts_network`.

website URL :  `https://speech.sts:2000/`

I then wrote a test scripts to run automation steps on the website.
The test will be executed in docker as well, by using the docker run command:

```
docker run     -v `pwd`/reports:/opt/robotframework/reports:Z     -v `pwd`/test:/opt/robotframework/tests:Z     -e BROWSER=chrome     ppodgorsek/robot-framework:latest
```

The test script failed due to

```
| FAIL |
Error: page.goto: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED at https://speech.sts:2000/
```

How do make the docker run to reach the website?

This is the dockerfile:

```
FROM fedora:36

MAINTAINER Paul Podgorsek <ppodgorsek@users.noreply.github.com>
LABEL description Robot Framework in Docker.

# Set the reports directory environment variable
ENV ROBOT_REPORTS_DIR /opt/robotframework/reports

# Set the tests directory environment variable
ENV ROBOT_TESTS_DIR /opt/robotframework/tests

# Set the working directory environment variable
ENV ROBOT_WORK_DIR /opt/robotframework/temp

# Setup X Window Virtual Framebuffer
ENV SCREEN_COLOUR_DEPTH 24
ENV SCREEN_HEIGHT 1080
ENV SCREEN_WIDTH 1920

# Setup the timezone to use, defaults to UTC
ENV TZ UTC

# Set number of threads for parallel execution
# By default, no parallelisation
ENV ROBOT_THREADS 1

# Define the default user who'll run the tests
ENV ROBOT_UID 1000
ENV ROBOT_GID 1000

# Dependency versions
ENV ALPINE_GLIBC 2.35-r0
ENV AWS_CLI_VERSION 1.22.87
ENV AXE_SELENIUM_LIBRARY_VERSION 2.1.6
ENV BROWSER_LIBRARY_VERSION 12.2.0
ENV CHROMIUM_VERSION 99.0
ENV DATABASE_LIBRARY_VERSION 1.2.4
ENV DATADRIVER_VERSION 1.6.0
ENV DATETIMETZ_VERSION 1.0.6
ENV FAKER_VERSION 5.0.0
ENV FIREFOX_VERSION 98.0
ENV FTP_LIBRARY_VERSION 1.9
ENV GECKO_DRIVER_VERSION v0.30.0
ENV IMAP_LIBRARY_VERSION 0.4.2
ENV PABOT_VERSION 2.5.2
ENV REQUESTS_VERSION 0.9.2
ENV ROBOT_FRAMEWORK_VERSION 5.0
ENV SELENIUM_LIBRARY_VERSION 6.0.0
ENV SSH_LIBRARY_VERSION 3.8.0
ENV XVFB_VERSION 1.20

# By default, no reports are uploaded to AWS S3
ENV AWS_UPLOAD_TO_S3 false

# Prepare binaries to be executed
COPY bin/chromedriver.sh /opt/robotframework/bin/chromedriver
COPY bin/chromium-browser.sh /opt/robotframework/bin/chromium-browser
COPY bin/run-tests-in-virtual-screen.sh /opt/robotframework/bin/

# Install system dependencies
RUN dnf upgrade -y --refresh \
  && dnf install -y \
    chromedriver-${CHROMIUM_VERSION}* \
    chromium-${CHROMIUM_VERSION}* \
    firefox-${FIREFOX_VERSION}* \
    npm \
    nodejs \
    python3-pip \
    tzdata \
    xorg-x11-server-Xvfb-${XVFB_VERSION}* \
  && dnf clean all

# FIXME: below is a workaround, as the path is ignored
RUN mv /usr/lib64/chromium-browser/chromium-browser /usr/lib64/chromium-browser/chromium-browser-original \
  && ln -sfv /opt/robotframework/bin/chromium-browser /usr/lib64/chromium-browser/chromium-browser

# Install Robot Framework and associated libraries
RUN pip3 install \
  --no-cache-dir \
  robotframework==$ROBOT_FRAMEWORK_VERSION \
  robotframework-browser==$BROWSER_LIBRARY_VERSION \
  robotframework-databaselibrary==$DATABASE_LIBRARY_VERSION \
  robotframework-datadriver==$DATADRIVER_VERSION \
  robotframework-datadriver[XLS] \
  robotframework-datetime-tz==$DATETIMETZ_VERSION \
  robotframework-faker==$FAKER_VERSION \
  robotframework-ftplibrary==$FTP_LIBRARY_VERSION \
  robotframework-imaplibrary2==$IMAP_LIBRARY_VERSION \
  robotframework-pabot==$PABOT_VERSION \
  robotframework-requests==$REQUESTS_VERSION \
  robotframework-seleniumlibrary==$SELENIUM_LIBRARY_VERSION \
  robotframework-sshlibrary==$SSH_LIBRARY_VERSION \
  axe-selenium-python==$AXE_SELENIUM_LIBRARY_VERSION \
  PyYAML \
  # Install awscli to be able to upload test reports to AWS S3
  awscli==$AWS_CLI_VERSION

# Gecko drivers
RUN dnf install -y \
    wget \

  # Download Gecko drivers directly from the GitHub repository
  && wget -q "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/$GECKO_DRIVER_VERSION/geckodriver-$GECKO_DRIVER_VERSION-linux64.tar.gz" \
  && tar xzf geckodriver-$GECKO_DRIVER_VERSION-linux64.tar.gz \
  && mkdir -p /opt/robotframework/drivers/ \
  && mv geckodriver /opt/robotframework/drivers/geckodriver \
  && rm geckodriver-$GECKO_DRIVER_VERSION-linux64.tar.gz \

  && dnf remove -y \
    wget \
  && dnf clean all

# Install the Node dependencies for the Browser library
# FIXME: Playright currently doesn't support relying on system browsers, which is why the `--skip-browsers` parameter cannot be used here.
RUN rfbrowser init \
  && ln -sf /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Browser/wrapper/node_modules/playwright-core/.local-browsers/firefox-1316/firefox/libstdc++.so.6

# Create the default report and work folders with the default user to avoid runtime issues
# These folders are writeable by anyone, to ensure the user can be changed on the command line.
RUN mkdir -p ${ROBOT_REPORTS_DIR} \
  && mkdir -p ${ROBOT_WORK_DIR} \
  && chown ${ROBOT_UID}:${ROBOT_GID} ${ROBOT_REPORTS_DIR} \
  && chown ${ROBOT_UID}:${ROBOT_GID} ${ROBOT_WORK_DIR} \
  && chmod ugo+w ${ROBOT_REPORTS_DIR} ${ROBOT_WORK_DIR}

# Allow any user to write logs
RUN chmod ugo+w /var/log \
  && chown ${ROBOT_UID}:${ROBOT_GID} /var/log

# Update system path
ENV PATH=/opt/robotframework/bin:/opt/robotframework/drivers:$PATH

# Set up a volume for the generated reports
VOLUME ${ROBOT_REPORTS_DIR}

USER ${ROBOT_UID}:${ROBOT_GID}

# A dedicated work folder to allow for the creation of temporary files
WORKDIR ${ROBOT_WORK_DIR}

# Execute all robot tests
CMD ["run-tests-in-virtual-screen.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Docker Network:

`docker network create sts_sts_network`

Then you modify your docker run command:

App1:
`docker run -v ... --network sts_sts_network`

App2:
`docker run -v ... --network sts_sts_network`

https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

Comment: still hitting same error Error: page.goto: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED at https://speech.sts:2000/

Comment: I use direct IP instead of hostname , then it works

Comment: For info, the Hostname "speech.sts" can not resolve. 

Inside a Docker network you can access between container with the "name" but not from host. For this you need an DNS service or point a Domain over a Proxy (Nginx) to the IP:PORT from your container. Maybe you musst EXPOSE the PORT in the Dockerfile "EXPOSE 2000"